# How to insert data in Oracle table with virtual columns?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, dataadapter

I have a .Net application that loads a datatable from an oracle Database. The table contains a virtual column.

When I'm inserting a new row in datatable, it says :

> Insert INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns

I do understand this error but I don't know how to skip the virtual columns when saving data back to the database.

Here is my code :

```
    Dim Command As OracleCommand
    Dim TempDataAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
    Dim DataSet = new DataSet
    Dim Name = "MyTable"
    Dim TempDataAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
    Dim DataTable as DataTable

    'The connection is defined somewhere else...
    Command = New OracleCommand("MyTable", Me.Connection) 
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    TempDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(Command)

    'Fill the table from the database 
    TempDataAdapter.FillSchema(DataSet, SchemaType.Source, Name)
    DataTable = DataTable = DataSet.Tables(0)
```

And the code for saving data back to database :

```
    TempDataAdapter.Update(DataTable)
```

After the creation of the datatable, I tried deleting the virtual column from the datatable :
        DataTable.Columns.Remove(DataTable.Columns("MyVirtualColumn"))

But when saving data back to the database, it returns the same error.

Can anyone help please ?

Cheers,

Comment: I have no idea what Dataadapter is, but a quick google search (really quick!) shows that it supports the concept of DataColumn Mappings. Apparently a table may support more than one mapping. You must create a mapping that maps only to the non-virtual columns, and name that mapping (rather than the table, generically) when you insert into it. See for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-datatable-and-datacolumn-mappings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not trying to populate or query the virtual column, can you create a view on that table that excludes the virtual column and work with that view.

Answer (score 2):

When you insert data into table with virtual columns then you must list columns, i. e. you must not use

```
Insert into table_x values (x, y, z)
```

but

```
Insert into table_x (col1, col2, col3) values (x, y, z)
```

Write your .net statements accordingly. If you try to update with `DataTable` then  you can use a view which excludes the virtual columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_MyTable AS 
SELECT col1, col2 -- skip virtual_col3 
FROM MyTable;
```

In case you like to select virtual columns but skip them for INSERT (or UPDATE) you can create a view with a INSTEAD OF Trigger. Would be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_MyTable AS 
SELECT col1, col2, virtual_col3
FROM MyTable;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER IO_MyTable
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON V_MyTable
    FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    IF UPDATING THEN
        UPDATE MyTable SET 
            col1 = :NEW.col1, 
            col2 = :NEW.col2
        WHERE primary_key_col = :OLD.primary_key_col;
    ELSIF INSERTING THEN
        INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2) VALUES (:NEW.col1, :NEW.col2);
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: That's not the solution. I'm not inserting data via SQL but Dataadapter...

Comment: No, that *is* the solution. One way or the other, you're going to have to change what you're doing.

Comment: @BobJarvis - That comment doesn't quite make sense. If the OP uses Dataadapter, he will need to use whatever functionality is available in that product, to map inputs just to non-virtual columns. He is looking to use Dataadapter, not to bypass it.